# MySQL ORDER BY CASE but keep duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, case, sql-order-by

I have a database with the format of

```
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
| word       | varchar(60)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| english_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |


| word | english_id |
| the  |          1 |
| of   |          2 |
| and  |          3 |
| a    |          4 |
| to   |          5 |
| in   |          6 |
| ant  |          7 |
| be   |          8 |
| that |          9 |
| was  |         10 |
```

I want to be able to order by the order of the input, but also to keep duplicates. So if they enter `"a cat and a dog"` I get the proper order with the SQL query below. The problem is that since I use `a` twice the second `a` doesn't appear. How do I keep duplicate values in order in the output? Here is the current query.

```
select english_id, word from english where word in ("Here", "are", "are", "dogs")
order by CASE word
  WHEN "here" then 1
  WHEN "are" then 2
  WHEN "are" then 3
  WHEN "dogs" then 4
END;
```

Here is its output

```
| english_id | word |
|        131 | here |
|         26 | are  |
|       1679 | dogs |
```

I want it to look like this

```
| english_id | word |
|        131 | here |
|         26 | are  |
|         26 | are  |
|       1679 | dogs |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get `are` to show up twice, you need to join to a "table" where `are` shows up twice. You can get the table like this:

```
SELECT 'Here'
UNION ALL SELECT 'are'
UNION ALL SELECT 'are'
UNION ALL SELECT 'dogs'
```

Just join your `english` table to that in a query, and it should work fine:

```
SELECT english_id, english.word
FROM english
JOIN (
    SELECT 'Here' AS word
    UNION ALL SELECT 'are'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'are'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'dogs') WordsToSearch ON english.word = WordsToSearch.word
ORDER BY CASE word
  WHEN "here" then 1
  WHEN "are" then 2
  WHEN "are" then 3
  WHEN "dogs" then 4
  END;
```

You can also specify the order information in your word list to simplify the query a bit:

```
SELECT english_id, english.word
FROM english
JOIN (
    SELECT 'Here' AS word, 1 AS word_order
    UNION ALL SELECT 'are', 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 'are', 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 'dogs', 4) WordsToSearch ON english.word = WordsToSearch.word
ORDER BY WordsToSearch.word_order;
```

**Addendum**

OP ran into trouble with the query as originally posted because the column `word` in the first line of the query wasn't aliased, and very kindly posted the updated query in the comments. The queries above have been updated for this fix.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm confused by what WordsToSearch is though? My database is named language.

Comment: `WordsToSearch` is the alias for the `SELECT ... UNION SELECT ... UNION SELECT` query. I made the name up. You can use any name you want here.

Comment: Excellent thank you for the help. I just made this small change and it worked SELECT english_id, english.word
FROM english
JOIN (
    SELECT 'Here' AS word, 1 AS word_order
    UNION ALL SELECT 'are', 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 'are', 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 'dogs', 4) WordsToSearch ON english.word = WordsToSearch.word
ORDER BY WordsToSearch.word_order;

Comment: Great catch @tomato_paste - thanks! I've fixed the queries in my answer to alias the `word` column.